# How to look up the element in the HTML in the .vue file that needs to be updated:

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

You can consider me a toddler in the **vuejs** worlđ

In my  app i fetch some posts that are present in firebase database

Each post has a **upvote** and **downvote** button just like stack overflow where users can upvote or downvote( it's completely u to them)

*Eeverything like votes getting updated to databae and rest all works great**

**Here comes the problem**

Firebase provides a event listener for listening whenever there is change in each child i.e  **post** (in my case upvotes. Downvotes)

i add this listener to the `created()` lifecycle hook so that the votes update when there is change in them by other users

**here is the simplified code below of my .vue file**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="post in posts" id="post.key" class="container">
            <p id="upvotes">{{ post.up}}</p>
            <p id="downvotes">{{ post.down }}</p>
          </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default{
        created:{
            const ref = this.$firebase.database().ref(); 
                ref.child("posts").on('child_changed', function(post) {
                    var upvotes = post.val().up;
                    var downvotes = post.val().down;
                    
                    //how to look up the element in the HTML above that needs to be updated:
                    //if it were plain javascript we would have done something like this
                    
                    //var postElm = document.getElementById(post.key);
                    //postElm.getElementById("upvotes").innerHTML = upvotes;
                    //postElm.getElementById("downvotes").innerHTML = downvotes;
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

My issue:

- how to look up the upvotes and downvotes element in the HTML above in the template that needs to be updated:
- according to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) we can register a reference `ref` to an element but there is this note saying:

**because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! `$refs` is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in templates for data-binding.**

*so how can I reference the elements to update them*

Comment: I think `$refs` are available in the `mounted` lifecycle hook. But I also suspect you're approaching this in the wrong way. I just don't understand well enough what you're trying to do to say what the right way is.

Comment: @RoyJ as many users will be upvoting or downvoting i want the updated values of the votes,,,,for that i am using the firebase event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Here is an example where I have mocked the firebase behavior. `posts` should be a `data` item, because you control its contents. `computed` items are for derived values based on other `data` or `props` items. You wouldn't make a `computed` based on a value external to Vue, because such values are not reactive.

```js
const payloads = [{
    val() {
      return {
        key: 2,
        up: 10,
        down: 3
      };
    }
  },
  {
    val() {
      return {
        key: 1,
        up: 3,
        down: 10
      };
    }
  }
];


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    postVoter: {
      template: '#post-voter-template',
      data() {
        return {
          posts: [{
              key: 1,
              up: 0,
              down: 0
            },
            {
              key: 2,
              up: 1,
              down: 0
            },
            {
              key: 3,
              up: 0,
              down: 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      created() {
        const i = setInterval(() => {
          if (payloads.length) {
            console.log("Doing");
            const post = payloads.shift();
            const item = this.posts.find((p) => p.key === post.val().key);

            item.up = post.val().up;
            item.down = post.val().down;
          } else {
            console.log("Done");
            clearInterval(i);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="post-voter-template">
    <div>
        <div v-for="post in posts" class="container">
            <p id="upvotes">{{ post.up}}</p>
            <p id="downvotes">{{ post.down }}</p>
          </div>
    </div>
</template>

<post-voter id="app"></post-voter>
```

You should be finding which data item needs updated, rather than trying to find it in the DOM. You don't say how `posts` is created or populated, so I'm having to surmise what it looks like. The code should go something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="post in posts" class="container">
            <p id="upvotes">{{ post.up}}</p>
            <p id="downvotes">{{ post.down }}</p>
          </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default{

        created() {
            const ref = this.$firebase.database().ref(); 

            ref.child("posts").on('child_changed', (post) => {
                const item = this.posts.find((p) => p.key === post.key);

                item.up = post.val().up;
                item.down = post.val().down;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I use vuex actions for asynchronous fetching of post and push them to post[ ] array in the state then I retrieve this post[ ] array using getters.

Comment: The issue with your answer is 'this' in the event listener is pointing null , so i used var self = this; outside the event listener and the null problem is solved but still it is not getting updated.

Comment: If you use arrow-function notation as I did, `this` should be correct. If you want to use the `function` keyword, you need to set a variable or bind.

Comment: Is `posts` declared as a `data` item, or as a `prop`? Do you know whether `find` actually found an item?

Comment: posts are declared as computed properties since new posts keep getting added.

Comment: ya tried that too but no change,,,,i will try putting the event listener in vuex actions then committing a mutation to change the posts [ ] array. Then i will let you if it works.